# mysql_fetch cannot collect all the data in database

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have here a code for the selection of all the data from the database, here's my code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['cname'];

if ($_POST["Search"] == "Search") {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parts WHERE cname LIKE '%$name%'");
    if (!empty($query)) {
        $vsi = 'No Data';
        $date = 'No Data';
        $cname = 'No Data';
    }

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $vsi = $row["vsi"];
        $date = $row["date"];
        $cname = $row["cname"];
    }
```

and here is how i echo all the variables,

```
<tr class="gradeC">
<?php echo "<td width='10%'><font size='-2'> $vsi </font></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td width='20%'><font size='-2'>$date</font></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td width='20%'><font size='-2'> $cname</font></td>" ?>
</tr>
```

My problem is that,

i only get one result from each row but my data in the database are 5.

here is my result

```
vsi      date             name
123      12/12/2012       test1
```

but the correct result should be:

```
vsi      date             name
123      12/12/2012       test1
123      12/12/2012       test1
123      12/12/2012       test1
123      12/12/2012       test1
123      12/12/2012       test1
```

note,

i make all the data in the database all the same

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: There's only one `$vsi` (and `$date` and `$cname`), so there's only one line.

Comment: Are you echoing the results *inside* or *after* the loop?

Comment: but their id is not the same, its auto increment.

Comment: once you fetch result form fetch array the pointer set to the end

Comment: even if i change the data in the database the result is the same, one data only.

Comment: @Jerome : Did you tried the answers given below ?

Comment: not yet, im sorry, my internet was down last day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use TR in while loop.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['cname'];

if ($_POST["Search"] == "Search") {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parts WHERE cname LIKE '%$name%'");
    if (!empty($query)) {
        $vsi = 'No Data';
        $date = 'No Data';
        $cname = 'No Data';
    }

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $vsi = $row["vsi"];
        $date = $row["date"];
        $cname = $row["cname"];

?>
<tr class="gradeC">
<?php echo "<td width='10%'><font size='-2'> $vsi </font></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td width='20%'><font size='-2'>$date</font></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td width='20%'><font size='-2'> $cname</font></td>" ?>
</tr>
<?
    }

?>
```

---

### **Warning**

your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you need to escape all `get` and `post` and the better approach will be using [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

**Good Read**

1. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. [**Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1723893)

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

I Hope this helps.

Comment: also in if function isnt it ? btw +1

Comment: Thanks NullPointer for Edit :)

Comment: yours welcome .. just tried to not give duplicate answer ... so improved existing answer ..

Answer (score 0):

The result of fetching will be an array. It will contain all of your matching database entries. But your echo is just outside of the while loop.Thats why it return only one result.Close the 2nd while loop after your echo.

```
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$vsi = $row["vsi"];
$date = $row["date"];
$cname = $row["cname"];

?>
<tr class="gradeC">
<?php echo "<td width='10%'><font size='-2'> $vsi </font></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td width='20%'><font size='-2'>$date</font></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td width='20%'><font size='-2'> $cname</font></td>" ?>
</tr>
<?
}
```